# Coin-agnostic API?

Tags: api

Are there any open APIs that connect to different cryptocurrencies, either with built-in capability or flexibility for plugins? Most APIs appear engineered for only one currency, usually just doge or btc. I'm wondering if there's a simpler, more adaptable solution than these coin-specific solutions, such that I could connect to multiple currencies from one code base.

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I am pretty new to cryptocurrencies, and my goal is to learn and interact with them in the most beneficial, efficient way possible.

Languages preferred include python, js, C, julia, java, R. That's just a preference, not a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BitcoinLib](https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib) is coin-agnostic, as long as you're dealing with a bitcoin-derived cruptocurrency. It is written in C# and has built-in support for bitcoin and litecoin. It comes with built-in support for on-the-fly coin configuration, with the use of the generic interface `ICryptocoinService`.

Sample configurations:

```
IBitcoinService BitcoinService = new BitcoinService();

ILitecoinService LitecoinService = new LitecoinService();

ICryptocoinService cryptocoinService = new CryptocoinService("daemonUrl", "rpcUsername", "rpcPassword", "walletPassword");
```

Repo: https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib